# Stop a program but not exit it?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a simple program for school with `if else` statements. I want script to stop after the first question, if it doesn't meet the criteria, without closing the program. Here is what I have so far:

```
age=int(input("How old are you? ")) #add a line to skip the other two inputs if not old enough
#registered = input("Are you a registered voter? yes/no ").lower()[:1]
#precinct   = input("Are you in your registered precinct? yes/no ").lower()[:1]

if age >= 18:
    print("You are old enough to vote. ") #Determines if old enough to vote.

else:
    print("You are not old enough to vote. ")


registered = input("Are you a registered voter? yes/no ").lower()[:1]

if registered == 'y':
    print("You are registered to vote. ")

else:
    print("Do you have documentation showing your permanent address? ")

precinct   = input("Are you in your registered precinct? yes/no ").lower()[:1]

if precinct == 'y':
    print("You are in your precinct and can vote. ")

else:
    print("You must be in your precinct to be able to vote. ")


if age >= 18 and registered == 'y' and precinct == 'y':
    print("Congratulations you may vote! ")

else:
    print("Sorry you may not vote. ")
```

Comment: Its not clear what you mean by "stop". Usually when we speak of a program stopping it means that the program exits.

Comment: If you want the program to quit you can just call the function `quit()`, wherever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an empty `input()` to make the program pause without exiting. It requires pushing enter to advance the program.

```
age = int(input("How old are you? "))

if age >= 18:
    print("You are old enough to vote. ") #Determines if old enough to vote.
else:
    print("You are not old enough to vote. ")
    input()  # Program is paused until enter is pressed
```